# What type/format of sheet music is this?

Tags: sheet-music

With zero experience in anything related to music (except listening to music :P), I started my journey in learning to play the guitar yesterday, and I'm following a tutorial on Youtube. I noticed on one of the tutorial videos that the presenter is using a very simple and convenient sheet music type/format to present his lessons. Now I want to find an app that creates sheet music in the same format but the problem is that I don't know what the type/format is called. If anyone can please point me in the right direction, I'd be most appreciative, and bonus points to anyone who knows an app in which I can create my own sheet music in this format.

To clarify, my main reason for asking this question is simply to find out what the name of the type/format of sheet music is, not to get app suggestions.

[image]

If you need another sample of the above, check out the video that I found it on, [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SV2ehlxGEFw).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check chordify it is a site which you upload any mp3 or mp4, YouTube, and they send back to you the chords of the song which you can print. Added value there are a few kinds of chords you can get piano chords or tab (guitar chords ) etc. Hope I was of help. This is the site. https://chordify.net/

Comment: Sure, check out Chordify.   Then, when you realise what a terrible job it does, un-check it.

Answer (score 3):

'Chord sheet with lyrics'?  I don't think there's a special name for this particular layout.

There are a lot of programs that will do this, and much more.   Think of it as full notation, with a zero-line stave and no actual notes.   There are probably even some programs that will do JUST this :-)

You might ask yourself whether a computer is a better tool for this job than pen and paper.

Comment: Other terms: "lead sheet", "fake book"...

Comment: A Lead Sheet or Fake Book would normally include the notated melody line.

Answer (score 0):

That's commonly called "TAB" which is short for tablature though this actually is anything but tablature (actual tablature indicates which exact notes on which frets to play).  But web searching for a "tab" of a song will mostly deliver this kind of information.

More accurately it is a song sheet or chord sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You may have some luck searching for "lead sheet" though i think that may also contain the melody it may get you what you need.

> A lead sheet is a form of musical notation that specifies the
>   essential elements of a popular song: the melody, lyrics and harmony.
>   The melody is written in modern Western music notation, the lyric is
>   written as text below the staff and the harmony is specified with
>   chord symbols above the staff.

source of above and more info on lead sheet here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead_sheet

Answer (score 0):

I generally hear those called "chord charts", or rarely "guitar charts". If I wanted to find one for a particular song, I'd Google "chord chart `songname` `author`", or something like that.

Some other terms:

- **Lead Sheet** implies a notated melody line (and possibly notated riffs)
- **Tab** or **Tablature** implies a type of notation based around finger positions, not pitches. Often used for guitar and other fretted stringed instruments
- **Sheet music** is more likely to include full musical notation, but can be used as a catch-all term for the above as well.

I created a few of these last week. I used Microsoft Word. Any text editor will do. Notepad is fine. It's nice if you can line up the chord changes above the appropriate words. Some of the better "notated" examples use `|` to represent bars, and occasionally `-` to represent beats. Like this:

```
C          | Am          |
Spider-Pig, Spider-Pig,
F   -   -   Am | G             |
Does whatever a Spider-Pig does.
```

If you need more specific rhythmic stuff notated, it's probably best to move to a lead sheet.